# Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://127.0.0.1:35357/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL. Unauthorized(HTTP 401)

Tags: openstack-swift

I am using openstack container to enable integration testing against swift

The container used is : https://hub.docker.com/r/jeantil/openstack-swift-keystone-docker/

And the steps followed are : https://github.com/jeantil/openstack-swift-keystone-docker

The configuration is working fine on local and open internet(concourse pipeline job)

**But when I am using the same in concourse pipeline job on INTRANET, I am getting the below error:**

Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://127.0.0.1:35357/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Unauthorized (HTTP 401)

I am getting this error while creating a new service or even loading user lists:

Example:

openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne object-store internal [http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/KEY_%\(tenant_id\)s](http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/KEY_%%5C(tenant_id%5C)s)

openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne object-store admin http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1

openstack user list

Is it due to some proxy related configuration, because everything is working fine if I am running this concourse job on internet

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple approaches and at the end I was able to solve the issue.

Include **ENV NO_PROXY=localhost** in the dockerfile so that the proxy configurations are removed for this config